# Cout fixes bug in C++ program, but why?

Tags: c++, cout

I wrote a simple program to grab stock prices from yahoo finance.    The loop that reads the data was truncating early (and ending about where the data from the website shows as opposed to the full download to the correct date for the excell file).   So I put in a cout command in the loop to try to debug and voila, it worked correctly!

So why does using the cout function alter the program function?  Any ideas?   Below is the code.  (I found two related posts, but still cant figure it out, e.g. "Can cout alter variables somehow?" and "Weird Error in C++ Program: Removing Printout Breaks Program")

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HINTERNET hOpen, hURL;
    LPCWSTR NameProgram = L"Webreader"; // LPCWSTR == Long Pointer to Const Wide String 
    LPCWSTR Website;                    
    char file[101];
    int i;
    string filename;        
    unsigned long read;

    filename = "data.txt";
    ofstream myFile(filename);
    if (! myFile)
    {
        cout < "Error opening file\n";
    }
    if ( !(hOpen = InternetOpen(NameProgram, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0 )))
    {
        cerr << "Error in opening internet" << endl;
        return 0;
    }                       
    Website = L"http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT&a=00&b=1&c=2009&d=09&e=22&f=2010&g=d&ignore=.csv";
    hURL = InternetOpenUrl( hOpen, Website, NULL, 0, 0, 0 ); //Need to open the URL
    InternetReadFile(hURL, file, 100, &read);
    file[read] = '\0';
    myFile << file;
    while (read == 100)
    {
        InternetReadFile(hURL, file, 100, &read);
        file[read] = '\0';
        myFile << file;
        cout << file; //If I take this line out, the function terminates early.
    }
    myFile << file;
    InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly your code?  `cout < "Error..."` looks suspicious...

Comment: You are right that was a bug, but it is in my program (I dont know why it compiled) so I just changed it to << and still get the same issue, cout fixes the other problem.  (Thanks for noticing that!)

Comment: A coding tip: You can collapse the initial read into your loop by using a do-while instead of a regular while.

Comment: Your read variable is uninitialized. that may be the problem

Comment: No, it's set by the first call to `InternetReadFile`, regardless of error conditions in that function (the first thing it does is set it to 0).

Comment: Your logic looks flawed to me - I've never used that API, but TCP is a byte stream protocol and many APIs only block until they have some data, rather than waiting for the requested amount.  Online InternetReadFile docs say "To ensure all data is retrieved, an application must continue to call the InternetReadFile function until the function returns TRUE and the lpdwNumberOfBytesRead parameter equals zero.", and "InternetReadFile can return with less data in lpBuffer than requested.".  You should follow that protocol carefully to avoid retrieving only part fo the document.

Answer (score 7):

What you have is a "Heisenbug", one which disappears when you try to find it. Make no mistake, the problem is still there and you *do* need to find it.

The *first* thing you should be doing is checking the return code of `InternetReadFile`.

In addition, you should *not* assume that a successful read will return the full 100 bytes, even if there are more to come. The [doco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385103%28VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> To ensure all data is retrieved, an application must continue to call the `InternetReadFile` function until the function returns `TRUE` and the `lpdwNumberOfBytesRead` parameter equals zero.
>
> : : :
>
> Also, converted lines might not completely fill the buffer, so `InternetReadFile` can return with less data in `lpBuffer` than requested.

In other words, I would add:

```
BOOL rc;
```

and change your two:

```
InternetReadFile(hURL, file, 100, &read);
```

statements to:

```
rc = InternetReadFile(hURL, file, 100, &read);
```

then your loop becomes:

```
while ((!rc) || (read > 0))   // I *think* that's right.
```

Comment: Bravo!  I changed the code to say while (reed != 0) and it worked!!  Thanks!

Comment: The idea that the cout function takes time and that changed the operation of the program was a nice insight--I never would have thought.   And I will put the above code in to verify all has been read by InternetReadFIle.  Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 6):

Doing a bit of output probably takes a little time, during which data can arrive from the net, ready to be read by your next call to `InternetReadFile`.

I haven't used that beast but if it works like other read-functions then it doesn't necessarily read 100 bytes, it may read anything less.

And if so then don't use `read == 100` as continuation condition for your loop. Use e.g. `read > 0`. But do check the *documentation*, it should tell you what to expect.

Depending on how low-level that function is, it may also be that zero bytes read doesn't mean finished. It might be that you need to check the return value. And e.g. do a little delay before going on.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Thanks to you as well!!!    (Bravo!  I changed the code to say while (reed != 0) and it worked!!)   (You guys are great!)

Comment: @GaryWhite If this solved your problem you should accept this answer.